# Pass parameters to javafx object written in Jython

Tags: java, oop, javafx, jython

I wrote an object in Jython to load multiple files using javaFX. Since the structure is very "rigid", I don't know how to pass parameters to this object without breaking it.

```
import sys

from java.io import File
from java.nio.file import Paths
from javafx.application import Application
from javafx.stage import FileChooser, Stage


class fileBrowser(Application):
    @classmethod
    def main(cls):
        fileBrowser.launch(cls)

    @staticmethod
    def getAbsPath(primaryStage):
        fc = FileChooser()
        fc.setInitialDirectory(
            File(Paths.get(".").toAbsolutePath().normalize().toString())
        )
        return fc.showOpenMultipleDialog(primaryStage)

    def start(self, primaryStage):
        self.getAbsPath(primaryStage)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    fb = fileBrowser
    fb.main()
```

For example, I wish I could pass a parameter to the function  `setInitialDirectory`.
**However it is important that any parameters passed can go under the start method**.
If I use the constructor `def __init__(self)` the program breaks.
So I wonder... How do I pass a parameter to the object that is read in the start method?? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Rewrite this in java?

Comment: But I need to write it in Jython! 